# ASP.NET Enable generating insert statements for views. Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, view, datasource

When i create a new datasource for a view, the "Generate insert, update and delete statements" checkbox is disabled. Is there any way to enable it?
(I need to insert to a view, which has a trigger "instead of insert". Writing to a table is impossible).

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if you have primary key in the tables you are trying to include in your datasource? If you don't try assigning a primary key and try again.

Comment: I'm not including tables, i'm including views.